# Chaining vanilla javascript traversal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
    <div class="panel-body"></div>
</div>
```

I am currently selecting the parent node of the `panel-heading` element like so:

```
e.target.parentNode
```

This leaves me with the `panel` class. All is well.

But now I would like to grab the `panel-body` at that point. Doing something like this unfortunately does not work:

```
e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.panel-body')
```

Is there a clean way to do this in vanilla javascript?

Comment: What you have works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhncqsxe/. What's the issue you have with it?

Comment: I am getting null returned. Your example also does not seem to do much for me.

Comment: try using `e.currentTarget.parentNode` or `this.parentNode` ... if there are children in element you assign listener to `target` can be a child. Beyond that show full code context as per [mcve]

Comment: @Stephan-v what do you mean by 'does not do much'? It shows that the element has been selected by both adding the class to it and logging it in the console

Comment: Please add the code with which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: if `e.target.parentNode` _is_ `.panel-header` then you'll need to search from _its_ parent. `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.panel-body')` - I could be misreading your question tho. It's ambiguous to me if "I am currently selecting the parent node of the panel-heading element like so: e.target.parentNode" is true given the line that follows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the node's class, you can always use `document` object:

> ```
> var tgt = document.querySelector('.panel-body');
> ```

If you need to get nodes in the context of an event such as click, you can delegate.

> - Find node that is an ancestor of all of the nodes you wish to access.
>
>   - ex. `.panel`
> - Register the event on that node.
>
>   - ex. `panel.addEventListener('click', callback)`
> - During the bubbling phase, find the `event.target` by comparing it to the `event.currentTarget` (the node that is registered to the event)
>
>   - ex. `if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) {...`

**Click nodes and it's tag and class will be displayed.**
**Details are commented in snippet**

### Snippet

```js
// Reference top element
var panel = document.querySelector('.panel');

// Register .panel on click event
panel.addEventListener('click', highlight);


function highlight(e) {

  // if the clicked node is not .panel
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    // Get the clicked node's class
    var tgtClass = e.target.className;

    // Get the clicked node's tag
    var tgtTag = e.target.tagName;
  }

  /* Set the clicked node's tag and class 
  || as it's content.
  */
  e.target.textContent += ' ' + tgtTag + '.' + tgtClass;
}
```

```css
[class*=panel] {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel">
  <hgroup class='panel-heading-group'>
    <h1 class="panel-heading">HEADING</h1>
    <h2 class='panel-sub-heading'>SUB-HEADING</h2>
  </hgroup>
  <main class="panel-body">
    <p>CONTENT A</p>
    <p>CONTENT B</p>
  </main>
  <footer class='panel-footer'>FOOTER</footer>
</section>
```